# Excel: disable "Error in loading DLL" message

Tags: excel, dll

I am building a data validation system (to check entries in cells) that is referring to a dynamically built named range. Sometimes the range does not exist and I have the "Error in loading DLL message".. is there a way to disable it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to know wether the error was triggered then try this:

```
On Error Resume Next
<code accessing the named range>
On Error Goto 0
```

If you need a way to check wether the error would have been raised:

```
Dim flag as Boolean
flag = False

On Error Resume Next
<code accessing the named range>
flag = True
On Error Goto 0
```

Flag will only become True if the critical code has been executed successfully

I know its dirty but so is VBA ;o)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am actually building it using spreadsheet functions only and was wondering whether there was a way to globally turn this alert off. Thanks.